# Web workers not spawning sub workers in firefox 10

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker, spawn

I've been trying to use web workers in Firefox 10.  The example on the Mozilla site computes Fibonacci numbers (in this case, the 5th Fibonacci number - 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers#section_11

When I click the link to go to the example page: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/workers/fibonacci/
I get the correct output of 5.  When I copy and paste the source code into a new file on my desktop, along with the associated worker script (fibonacci.js), it won't work beyond the third number (i.e. worker.postMessage("3");).  I've tried running it off my web server with the same result.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

in the script, when n >=3, it spawns a new worker. 
But spawning sub workers isn't supported in Chrome/Safari yet.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Spawning_subworkers

Which Browser are you trying it on ?

Comment: you should have read the question properly.. he does mention Firefox 10 clearly..